# How to merge multiple rows into single row if the id is same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
id   name   
2    ravi kumar    
2    mohit kumar   
...
```

and I want to result

```
id name   
2 ravi kumar / mohit kumar    
...
```

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/545672/7235947 Check this link . I hope it will help you.

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ :please look at this link to improve question

Comment: also please tag the DBMS you are using ,along with the version

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can resolve the issue:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT '/' + Name
         FROM Table1 t2
         WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') data
FROM Table1 t1;
```